# Slider Appearance Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, slider, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to customize a slider in Xamarin.Forms,for example how change the progress bar of slider or how to change for an image, somebody can give me idea about that ?

Comment: You will need to create a custom renderer in the platform specific project. Please have a look at the following link: [Customizing Controls for Each Platform](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)

Comment: Thanks Blanthor i will try that.

Comment: @RicardoRomo Do you have a solution for this? Can you please post?

Comment: Yes, I made a custom render of slider, I don't have any sample at this moment but I chill check if i have one If i find it I will share you. @Lijo

Comment: @RicardoRomo It would be great if you can post the custom renderer you used.